# OpenGraph Image is fine in the debugger, doesn't show on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, xfbml

If you view the [source code](http://www.thejoecole.com/gallery/Places/Garden_of_the_Gods-1/photo-IMG_0325.jpg#IMG_0325.jpg) of an example page, and the [Facebook debugger for that page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.thejoecole.com%2Fgallery%2FPlaces%2FGarden_of_the_Gods-1%2Fphoto-IMG_0325.jpg%23IMG_0325.jpg), you will see that Facebook scrapes the correct image and displays it in the Facebook debugger. There are no weird redirects or filenames going on here, just a simple image set to og:image, but Facebook doesn't show it!

If you copy/paste the url directly on Facebook (for example, in a status update), the og:image shows up immediately.

However, when liking or commenting from the site, NO image shows up at all!

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

//create an object

FBGraphObject object;

//open graph object will be posted to facebook

object.provisionedForPost = YES;

Answer (score 0):

Putting your page into Facebook debugger produces this warning:

The image referenced by the url of og:image tag could not be downloaded.

It is also for some reason chopping the ends off the og tags in your page, deleting the 'IMG_0325.jpg' text.  I can only imagine this is because it doesn't like the capitalisation!

Our site has been suffering owing to a recent change in FB's acceptance of urls for images which it will show in posts, I think we have a slightly different problem to yours but they seem to have become more restrictive about the url being a very vanilla image url.

Comment: The link to the facebook debugger in your question is directly to the image rather than to the page in which it appears, try putting http://www.thejoecole.com/gallery/Places/Garden_of_the_Gods-1 into the debugger.  It also mentions the image isn't large enough.

Comment: Well that's for a very good reason. The image has its own unique URL, and the facebook comment/like functionality only appears on those pages, so the main page that the image appears on doesn't have a specific og:image set. However, once you open an image in fancybox, the comments/like apply only to that URL - the specific image url. And in debugger, these URLs work just fine. Those are the URLs that are being liked/commented on, and they work just fine in debugger.